# Python Multiprocessing Computational Performance Optimisation

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I am currently working on implementing multiprocessing on a code segment which takes relatively long to run. It is basically applying a very elaborate function a fair number of times. At the moment I am utilising the following syntax:

```
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    pool = Pool(4)
    results = pool.map(function,data) 
    pool.close()
    output = pool.join()
```

My CPU consists of 4 cores, hence the Pool(4). I see from my CPU usage that when implementing multiprocessing all 4 pools are using approximately 25% of the available CPU, in contrast to one CPU core using 25% when not using multiprocessing. However, I see that the four CPU cores are using a significantly lower amount of memory: approximately 45k each in contrast to almost 550k when running on one CPU core without multiprocessing (a lack of memory does not seem to be the issue as it remains at approximately 27% utilisation throughout). The computation takes approximately 5 minutes on one CPU core, and stil has not finished for an hour when running on all 4. Could somebody shine some expert views on what may be the root cause of this inefficiency?

Happy coding!

Comment: Does it finish if you use `Pool(1)`?

Comment: Don't know why, but I have similar issue with using multiprocessing in Jupyter. It just won't finish. But when I implement function in file and then import it, everything works. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @thebjorn Thank you for your swift reply. It is currently still running as we speak with Pool(1), more than 8 minutes have passed already. At the moment it is still capped at 25% CPU usage with only 40k usage of memory. It therefore seems that the lack of allocated memory seems to be the root cause of the long run time.Do you support this conclusion?

Comment: @Kopytok Do you mean defining the function in a seperate file and importing it into the main file? If you mean that, I'll give that a go !

Comment: Sounds more like you're hitting a deadlock.  I'm assuming you've heeded all the warnings about `data` being pickleable etc., and that it is a list (iterable) and not a single data point. Try commenting out the `.close()` and `.join()` calls to see if that is where you're waiting. Finally, replace `function` with something that writes to a file when the function starts, arguments, return values, etc. so you can verify that something is happening.

Comment: ps: I'm assuming you're running this from the command line, and not e.g. from the interactive Python prompt...

Comment: @thebjorn I just did some more troubleshooting; I created a new function f(x) which returns the value for x^2, with an input list with entries 1 through 50. Even with this strongly simplified version, the code does not get past the "results" line and no results are shown anywhere. I presume that the conclusion with respect to a deadlock is correct. After doing some preliminary research into this topic, I'm not yet exactly sure how to fix this issue. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @thebjorn To add to your second question: I'm currently using Spyder, and simply running the script using F5. No direct coding in the interactive console is involved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spyder so I couldn't tell you if that has any special requirements.  More of your code is probably needed to get any more clues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, which sounds like your updated code, works for me:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def function(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    pool = Pool(1)
    data = range(50)
    results = pool.map(function, data)

    pool.close()
    output = pool.join()
    print results
    print 'in %.4f seconds' % (time.time() - start)
```

running it from the command line:

```
c:\srv\tmp> python mptest.py
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401]
in 0.2950 seconds
```

we can add some logging to `function`:

```
def function(x):
    print('inside function(%r)' % x)
    res = x * x
    print('returning from function(%r) => %r' % (x, res))
    return res
```

and running with `data = range(20)` and `pool = Pool(2)`, we can see the two processes fighting for the output:

```
c:\srv\tmp> python mptest.py
inside function(0)
inside function(3)returning from function(0) => 0

rinside function(1)eturning from function(3) => 9

rieturning from function(1) => 1nside function(4)

irnside function(2)eturning from function(4) => 16

rieturning from function(2) => 4nside function(5)

irnside function(6)eturning from function(5) => 25

irnside function(9)eturning from function(6) => 36

rieturning from function(9) => 81nside function(7)

irnside function(10)eturning from function(7) => 49

rieturning from function(10) => 100nside function(8)

irnside function(11)eturning from function(8) => 64

rieturning from function(11) => 121nside function(12)

irnside function(15)eturning from function(12) => 144

rieturning from function(15) => 225nside function(13)

irnside function(16)eturning from function(13) => 169

rieturning from function(16) => 256nside function(14)

irnside function(17)eturning from function(14) => 196

rieturning from function(17) => 289nside function(18)

returning from function(18) => 324
inside function(19)
returning from function(19) => 361
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
in 0.2700 seconds
```

Comment: I actually started to create this exact same example yesterday as well, but didn't yet get to completing it yet when I saw your reply. It does indeed seem to decrease computational time only for very large data ranges. What is surprising though is that "results = [function(x) for x in data]", which a friend suggested, does the same but in 1/4 of the computational time. In addition, implementing this strategy in my full code increases computational time by a factor of 10+. I would like to thank you for your efforts and will accept this answer.

Comment: @F0R0R welcome to the wonderful world of parallel computing where few things work according to expectations :-)  I'm guessing the time-sinks you're experiencing are related to one or more of: startup/teardown costs (processes need to be spun up and torn down -- think of how many machine instructions are required), communication costs (parameters and results need to be shipped to a separate process using the pickle/marshall modules, and similarly for the results), synchronization issues (locks/waits/cache invalidations/etc.). All parallel programs have these issues..